# Tertiary operator in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

How do we use ternary  operator in Kotlin?

I have tried using ternary operator in same manner that we use in java but I got a lint error in it:

```
var myVariable = (condition == true) ? value1 : value2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Valid Kotlin, but invalid Java/C#/JavaScript
var v = if (a) b else c
```

Alternative:

```
when(a) {
    true -> b
    false -> c
}
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.